# Verification of the limit of $(x-\sin(x))/(\tan(x)-x)$ as $x\to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, solution-verification

I would appreciate if someone could verify to me my answers.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{\tan(x)-x}$$I used L'Hopital's rule twice and got answer $1/2$.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1}{\sin(4x)}-\frac{1}{4x}$$ also I used L'Hopital's rule twice and got $0$.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow2^-}(x^2-4)\ln(2-x)$$I used L'Hopital's rule once and got $0$.

Thanks.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508733/lim-x-to0-fracx-sin-xx-tan-x-without-using-lhopital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer to the first problem has been given by GTX OC, let us focus on the second problem.
$$(x^2-4) \log(2-x) = (x-2)(x+2)\log(2-x)=-(x+2)(2-x)\log(2-x)$$
I suppose you know that $x \log(x)$ goes to 0 when $x$ goes to zero. Then, ... Are you able to continue with this ?

Comment: so my answer of $0$ is correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is indeed correct. We can use the power series for sinx and tanx to verify the answer.
We have
$$\sin(x)=x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!...$$
and $$\tan(x)=x+x^3/3+2x^5/15...$$
Substituting the above two series in your limit, we get
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{\tan(x)-x}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x-(x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!...)}{(x+x^3/3+2x^5/15...)-x}$$
Cancelling the x we get
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^3/3!-x^5/5!...}{x^3/3+2x^5/15...}$$
Dividing numerator and denominator by $x^3$ 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1/3!-x^2/5!+...}{1/3+2x^2/15+...}$$
Taking limits the x vanishes and you are left with
$$\frac{1/3!}{1/3}$$
Simplify to get $1/2$