# Solve limit without L'Hopital: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2 \sin x-\sin 2x}{x-\sin x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Taks: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2 \sin x-\sin 2x}{x-\sin x}$$

Is it possible to solve it without l'Hopital ?

Comment: Often you can use power series approximations. Here, use: $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)$$

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217081/determine-lim-x-to-0-fracx-sinxx3-frac16-without-lhospita?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the limit of $(2\sin x-\sin 2x)/(x-\sin x)$ as $x\to 0$ without L'Hôpital's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352117/find-the-limit-of-2-sin-x-sin-2x-x-sin-x-as-x-to-0-without-lh%c3%b4pitals)