# Calculating limit of function

Tags: limits

To find limit of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\cos(\sin x) - \cos x}{x^4} $.
I differentiated it using L Hospital's rule. I got
$$\frac{-\sin(\sin x)\cos x + \sin x}{4x^3}\text{.}$$ I divided and multiplied by $\sin x$.
Since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$, thus I got
$\frac{1-\cos x}{4x^2}$.On applying standard limits, I get answer $\frac18$. But correct answer is $\frac16$. Please help.

Comment: You might have to use l'Hopital's rule more than once.

Comment: But on doing so, it gets extremely complicated

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\neq 0$! It equals $1$.

Comment: **Hint**: Look that the $x^4$ at the denominator, it's asking for some [Taylor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) guy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$\cos(\sin x)-\cos x=2\sin\frac{x-\sin x}2\sin\frac{x+\sin x}2$$

So, $$\frac{\cos(\sin x)-\cos x}{x^4}=2\frac{\sin\frac{x-\sin x}2}{\frac{x-\sin x}2}\frac{\sin\frac{x+\sin x}2}{\frac{x+\sin x}2}\cdot\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\cdot\frac{x+\sin x}x\cdot\frac14$$

We know, $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}h=1$

$$\text{Apply L'Hospital's Rule on  }\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$$

$$\text{and we get }\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+\sin x}x=1+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x$$

Comment: @user2369284, $x\to0\implies x\pm\sin x\to0\implies\frac{x\pm\sin x}2\to0$

Comment: What is wrong with my solution

Comment: @user2369284, how have you separated $\frac{\sin x}x$ ?

Comment: lim X-> 0 (sin(sin x))/sin x = 0

Comment: @user2369284, then need to multiply $\cos x$ with $\sin x$

Comment: In the numerator, I divided by sin x to get $\frac{sin(sinx)}{sinx}cosx + 1$

Comment: @user2369284, we can write 
$$\frac{-\sin(\sin x)\cos x + \sin x}{4x^3}=\frac{-\frac{\sin(\sin x)}{\sin x}\sin x\cos x + \sin x}{4x^3}=\frac{-\sin2x+2\sin x}{8x^3}$$

Comment: But as we are getting -sin 2x and 2sin x, why not take sin x common and apply Lt x-> 0 (sin x)/x = 0.

Comment: I didn't know that these simple formulas had a magnificent technical name "Prosthaphaeresis Formulas." I am feeling enlightened! :) By the way this provides the simplest solution with one application of L'Hospital (+1)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, here(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/TrigonometricIdentities.html) we can avail many Trigonometric Identities by name. In India, they formulae are taught without such name.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, do you know how to avoid even one use of L'Hospital? (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhospital-rule-or-series-expansion)

Comment: sorry to say but there is no easy route to $(x - \sin x)/x^{3}$ without L'Hospital. Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437926/a-limit-problem-lim-limits-x-to-0-fracx-sin-sin-x-sin2xx6  for a long route

Answer (score 4):

*Without L'Hôpital*

The expansions $\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + O(x^5)$ and $\cos(u) = 1 - \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{u^4}{24} + O(u^6)$ combine joyfully to give
$$
\cos(\sin x) - \cos(x) = \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{5x^4}{24}\right) - \left(1-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}\right) + O(x^5)
$$
so finally,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(\sin x) - \cos(x)}{x^4} = \frac{5}{24}-\frac{1}{24} = \frac{1}{6}.
$$

Comment: Please tell what's wrong with my solution

Comment: @user2369284: $\sin(\sin x) \neq \sin(x)$

Comment: But where did I write that.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}2}{x^4} \to \frac1{24} \tag 1$$

therefore

$$\frac {\cos(\sin x) - \cos x}{x^4}=\frac{\sin^4 x}{x^4}\frac {\cos(\sin x) - 1+\frac{\sin^2 x}2}{\sin^4 x}-\frac{\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}2}{x^4}+\frac12\frac{x^2-\sin^2 x}{x^4}$$

therefore the given limit is equivalent to

$$\frac12\frac{x^2-\sin^2 x}{x^4}=\frac12\frac{x+\sin x}{x}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\to \frac12 \cdot 2 \cdot \frac16=\frac16$$

using that $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\to \frac16$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1337564/505767).

---

Proof of $(1)$, using that $\cos x=1-2\sin^2 \left(\frac x 2\right)$

$$\frac{\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}2}{x^4}=\frac{\frac{x^2}2-2\sin^2 \left(\frac x 2\right)}{x^4}=\frac18\frac{\left(\frac x 2\right)^2-\sin^2 \left(\frac x 2\right)}{\left(\frac x 2\right)^4} \to \frac1{24}$$

by the same previous result.