# Limit: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x-\sin x}{x-\tan x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Here's the question:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x-\sin x}{x-\tan x}$$

I've used l'Hospitals to get
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1-\cos x}{1-\sec^2x}$$
I then tried to use it again, resulting in $= \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \cfrac {\sin x}{1-\sec^2 x\cdot\tan^2 x}$ which gives me 0, but the wolfram alpha answer is $-1/2$.  I've tried other things like dividing by x, but nothing I get leads me to believe I'm on the right path.

Comment: $\dfrac {\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}(1-\sec^2 x) = -2 \tan x \sec^2 x$

Comment: See this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/438121/72031 Equation (7) of that answer is this limit in question. robjohn has done it without the use of L'Hospital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, firt use the l'Hospital rule:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x-\tan x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{1-\sec^2x} $$
Now, $\sec^2x=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$, then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x-\tan x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{1-\frac{1}{\cos^2x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{\frac{\cos^2x-1}{\cos^2x}} =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(1-\cos x)\frac{\cos^2x}{\cos^2x-1}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (1-\cos x)\frac{\cos^2x}{-(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}= $$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}-\frac{\cos^2x}{1+\cos x}=-\frac{1}{2}. $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\dfrac{1-\cos x}{1-\sec^2x} = \dfrac{1-\cos x}{1-\sec^2x} \cdot \dfrac{\cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x}= \dfrac{(1-\cos x)\cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x-1} = \dfrac{(1-\cos x)\cos^2 x}{-1(1-\cos^2 x)} $

Comment: Doesn't cos x = 1 at x=0? So then the last step would be (1-1)*1/-1*(1-1) = 0 would it not?

Comment: @Greener I didn't finish the problem. If you factor and cancel in the last step, you remove that issue and get the correct answer.

Comment: Okay, I didn't see that until later.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

After applying l'Hospital twice you get:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin x}{\frac{-2\sin x\cos x}{\cos^4 x}}$$, which tends to -1/2

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
By the Maclaurin expansion of $\sin x$ and $\tan x$, one have

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x-\tan x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{6}x^3-\frac{1}{120}x^5+\mathcal{o}(x^5)}{-\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{2}{15}x^5+\mathcal{o}(x^5)}$$