# Is it possible to solve this limit without Hopital / Taylor / derivatives: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3} = \frac{1}{6}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

It's simple to prove with Hopital that

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3} = \frac{1}{6}$$

Is it possible to solve this limit without Hopital or Taylor (without derivatives)?

Comment: See the beautiful answer by moderator robjohn http://math.stackexchange.com/a/438121/72031 From the answer it should be very obvious that the problem is very difficult if one fordbids the use of differentiation. This somehow shows the great power of differentiation.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/158134/1242

Answer (score 18):

Let us assume $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3} = L$$ (A finite quantity).

Now replace $x\rightarrow 3y$, then we get $$\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{3y-\sin 3y}{27y^3} = L$$

Now, using the formula $$\sin 3y = 3\sin y-4\sin^3 y$$

we get $$\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{3y-3\sin y+4\sin^3 y}{27y^3} = L$$

So $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{9}\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y-\sin y}{y^3}+\frac{4}{27}\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin y}{y}\right)^3=L$$

So $$\frac{1}{9}L+\frac{4}{27} = L\Rightarrow \frac{8}{9}L = \frac{4}{27}\Rightarrow L=\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: @juantheron This is a very interesting approach indeed. +1) Did you replace $x=3y$ because there is a cube in the denominator? I am trying to come up with some generalization...

Comment: Yes  imranfat You are Right.

Comment: @juantheron  Thank you very much!

Comment: What is really proved in this great solution is that if we assume that the limit exists then it equals to 1/6. The existence of the limits remains unproved.

Comment: Is there a way to show "that it is bounded near $0$" "without Hopital or Taylor (without derivatives)"? $\hspace{.44 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer You can probably use the same techniques (namely trig identities) that you use to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$, but I've not tried to work that out to see if it is correct.

Comment: I found another answer [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437926/a-limit-problem-lim-limits-x-to-0-fracx-sin-sin-x-sin2xx6/438121#438121)

Comment: First show that $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x-sin(x)}{x-tan(x)}=-\frac{1}{2}$$ then subtract 1 $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{tan(x)-sin(x)}{tan(x)-x}=\frac{3}{2}$$   then $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{tan(x)-x}{x^3}=\frac{1}{3}$$ and $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x-sin(x)}{x^3}=\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: If one consider any function defined arround zero then exactly one situation is true among thé following four situations. 1) the limit is +infinity 2) the limit is - infinity 3) the limit is some réal number 4) the limit is none of the above (so it do not existe as a réal number nor as +\- infinity) the proof  above is that if the possibility number 3) holds then that real number mentionned in that possibility is 1/6. It remains to prove that possibilités 1), 2) and 4) do not occur for the considéred function.