# Solving limits without l'Hopital

Tags: limits, asymptotics, limits-without-lhopital

I've encountered several limits that need to be solved in order to calculate the coefficients in asymptotic formulas for elementary functions, e.g.:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x -x}{x^3} $$

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} $$

Obviously, they're really easy with l'Hopital, but it's illegal since we haven't reached derivatives yet. Are they possible to solve without l'Hopital? Has anybody encountered the same task with asymptotic formulas, i.e.: finding coefficients for higher order asymptotic decompositions while knowing lower order coefficients?

Comment: Use the Taylor series expansion for $\sin x$ and $e^x$

Comment: Prohibited as well, since, well, no derivatives)

Comment: @tethernova That's a derivative.

Comment: @Van0k How else would you find asymptotic formulas for those functions?

Comment: Here is a link for the first one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495624/is-it-possible-to-solve-this-limit-without-hopital-taylor-derivatives The solution provided is very neat

Comment: For the second one I am a little bit confused. You have not learned derivatives yet, so how were you introduced to the e-power function?

Comment: @Dylan As I stated - recursively. I have to find formulas till x^3 included. I know that sin(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+o(x^3) and a=0, b=1, c=0, then I'm supposed to find d.

Comment: Ok I understand. It wasn't clear at all what you were doing, until now.

Comment: @imranfat Much obliged, but I'm afraid I still have just about 15 such limits to solve, and they're all different in terms of used functions. But still thanks a lot)

Comment: @Van0k If you need help from the MSE community, it is better to post one problem at a time rather than multiple problems in one post...

Comment: @imranfat Thank you for your advice, I've signed up pretty much 5 minutes ago

Comment: @imranfat: That solution doesn't show that the limit exists, it only gives the value of the limit *if* it exist. See here for an alternative: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157903/evaluation-of-lim-limits-x-rightarrow0-frac-tanx-xx3/158134#158134.

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, I understand, but without any derivatives/Taylor this is not easy to do. The OP might not be "there" yet...without the standard tools, it certainly isn't easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used numerical approximation.  For the first of your limits, since $x \rightarrow 0$, I substituted $x=.1,.01,.001,.0001$ etc.  The answer seemed to be limiting towards $-0.1666$ repeating, which is $x=-1/6$.  I assume the same can be done for the other.