# Show that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x\tan^{-1}x-x^2}{x^6}=\frac{2}{9}$

Tags: limits

Show that $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x\tan^{-1}x-x^2}{x^6}=\frac{2}{9}.$$

**Proceed:**
$$\tan x\tan^{-1}x=(x+\dfrac{1}{3}x^3+\dfrac{2}{15}x^5+O(x^7)) (x-\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^5+O(x^7))=x^2+\frac{2x^6}{9}+O(x^8)$$

Thus,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\tan x\tan^{-1}x-x^2}{x^6}
=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac1{x^6} \left(\frac{2x^6}{9}+O(x^8)\right)=\dfrac{2}{9}$$
Where is the problem?

Comment: First of all, you switch between problems in the middle of your text. Second, what is the difference between this problem and the problem you asked a few hours ago that has been deleted?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476795/show-that-lim-limits-x-to-0-frac-sin-x-sin-1x-x2x6-frac118

Comment: @NinadMunshi just answer the man's question. That's why people hate mathematicians...

Comment: You got the right conclusion. The limit is $2/9$. You need to fix the $\sin(x)\sin^{-1}(x)$, which is supposed to be $\tan(x)\tan^{-1}(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tan^{-1} x=x-x/^3/3-x^5/5+...,  \tan x=x+x^3/3+2x^5/15+...$$
Then $$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan x \tan^{-1} x-x^2}{x^{6}} =\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}  \frac{2x^6/9+x^8/45+...}{x^6}=\frac{2}{9.}$$