# Do you have set of advanced problems of limits?

Tags: limits, book-recommendation, online-resources

I’m currently practising questions on limits and have solved many problems of beginner level and one step above(medium level). Now I’m searching for set of advanced problems.I tried searching the web but there are mostly mediocre level problems and very few advanced level. So if anyone do have set of advanced problems or  knows some place from where I can get them, please share or tell

Your help will quench my thirst for advanced problems.

Comment: Unless you define what you mean by "mind-boggling" and "tricky" problems of limits, the answers to this post will be opinion-based.  And that is a legitimate reason to close this question.

Comment: What about Berman for the next level?

Comment: Why not search the unanswered questions here?

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya what is Berman?

Comment: There are plenty of examples here. For example try this $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\sin(\sin x) - \sin^2x}{x^6}$$ handled in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437926/72031). Evaluate it without looking at answers.